# Retrive an image from a field database path to a datagrid

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, datagrid

i need to put the logo team next to the team name, i have a table with the team name and a field named logo, how to retrive the logo who is stored in folder images directly from the path that is stored in a field in a table, 
I share a image of my table in order  for you experts give me an orientation of how achive that!
regards 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQbqE.png)

Comment: I need to put the logo in a datagrid!

Comment: What is the column type in the datagrid for image?

Comment: its a** varchar!**

Comment: I need datagrid read the path with the proper syntax to retrive the image!

Comment: Datagrid won't render image automatically based on the path. Instead you need to bind image based on the path from database.

Comment: tnks, do you have some examples for achive that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple to show image in data grid in asp.net .

```
 <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="IMAGE"  ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="img" ImageUrl='<%#(Eval("IMAGE"))%>'  runat="server" Width="40px" Height="50px" CssClass="pic zoom" />
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now allow your Data Table to have a Image column where you have your path saved of the images of logo here is my data table.

[image]

And it is output image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code. dataGridView1 is a DataGridView control.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        Persons.Add(new Person(1, "John", 5));
        Persons.Add(new Person(2, "Ed", 4));
        Persons.Add(new Person(3, "Sara", 3));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Persons;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public Image Star { get; set; }

    public Person(int rank, string name, int score)
    {
        Rank = rank;
        Name = name;
        Score = score;
        Star = DrawStarImage(score);
    }
    private Image DrawStarImage(int starCount)
    {
        var starIcon = Image.FromFile("E:\\temp\\download.jpg");

        // the image of all stars (the width has to be the width of one star multiplied by the count of stars)
        var image = new Bitmap(starCount * starIcon.Width, starIcon.Height);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < starCount; i++)
            {
                // place the star icon to its position in the loop
                int x = (i * starIcon.Width);

                // https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dbsak4dc(v=vs.110).aspx
                g.DrawImage(starIcon, x, 0, starIcon.Width, starIcon.Height);
            }

            g.Flush();
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```